# How can it preserve source mac address unchanged after layer-3 filtering through a Linux bridge (which using bridge-utils and ebtables)

Tags: linux, bridge, mac, filtering, ebtables

**Background:**
I have a Linux bridge (Ubuntu 15.10, 64bit, name *Bridge B*) with two physical interfaces, eth0 and eth1, and the bridge interface’s name is br0. *Send A* (Win 10) connects to eth0, and *Receiver C* (Win 10) connects to eth1. As shown in the figure below.

*Sender A* <------> (eth0) *Bridge B* (eth1) <------> *Receiver C*

*Sender A*’s MAC Address: D4:EE:07:3F:F9:0D, IP Address: 192.168.1.2
*Bridge B*’s eth0 MAC Address: B0:51:8E:FF:2F:C8, No IP Address
*Bridge B*’s eth1 MAC Address: B0:51:8E:FF:2F:C9, No IP Address
*Bridge B*’s br0 MAC Address is the same with eth0 (Auto), IP Address: 192.168.1.1
*Receiver C*’s MAC Address: 4C:CC:6A:DC:91:60, IP Address: 192.168.1.3

*Send A* send packet to *Receiver C*, such as icmp ping.

**Problem:**
Before I configure ebtable rule in *Bridge B* for redirecting packet to layer 3, everything is OK, *Receiver C* receive *Send A*'s ping packet with source MAC Address D4:EE:07:3F:F9:0D, and destination MAC Address 4C:CC:6A:DC:91:60, nothing changed after packet send out from *Send A*.

When I set up ebtable rules in *Bridge B* for redirecting forwarded packet to layer 3, then I can use iptables for packet filtering in *Bridge B*. Code is:

```
ebtables -t broute -A BROUTING -p IPv4 --logical-in br0 -j redirect
```

Then problem happened. Packet from *Send A* to *Receiver C* which through *Bridge B*'s layer 3, I can see in *Receiver C* that the source MAC Address of the packet is B0:51:8E:FF:2F:C8. Obviously, the source MAC Address is changed to *Bridge B*’s br0 MAC Address.

I am wondering the problem is that when packet is redirected from layer 2 to layer 3, and then reroute by *Bridge B* in layer 3, the source MAC Address then be changed by *Bridge B*’s kernel.

**Questing:**
Is there something I can do or configure to preserve source MAC Address unchanged after layer-3 filtering through *Bridge B*?

**/etc/network/interface** configuration in *Bridge B*

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
up ifconfig eth0 up

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
up ifconfig eth1 up

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
address 192.168.1.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
pre-up ip link set eth0 promisc on
pre-up ip link set eth1 promisc on
pre-up echo "1">/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
bridge_ports eth0 eth1
```

---

CGretski, I read the man page of ebtables in http://ebtables.netfilter.org/misc/ebtables-man.html. My personal understanding is that when using ebtables “-j redirect”, the redirect target will change the MAC ***target*** address to the bridge device, then the packet can be sent to bridge interface br0, as mentioned in the example above. So, a packet from *Sender A* to *Receiver C*, the target mac address will be changed to bridge’s mac address, nothing mention about source mac address whether will be changed or not.

After filtering by *Bridge B*’s layer 3 (or nothing done by layer 3), the packet now should be rerouted to *Receiver C*. Then the target mac address of the packet will be changed to *Receiver C*. But on the same time, packet’s source mac address be changed to *Bridge B*’s mac address.

If I use "-j accept" in ebtables target, as you advice, packet will not be sent to layer 3, and transparently pass through *Bridge B*, nothing be changed, including source and target mac address. But I cannot do any layer 3 filtering.

The reason I want to maintain packet’s layer2 information is that I do not want *Receiver C* to sense of any existence of device between *Sender A* and itself. Another imporent reason is that in some scenarios, *Receiver C* (especially when it is a gateway) will drop the packet after source mac and ip verification.

Answer (score 0):

Losing layer2 info is an expected side-effect of introducing Layer3 routing and is the very definition of the "-j redirect" target.

From ebtables man page:

> The redirect target will change the MAC target address to that of the
>   bridge device the frame arrived on.

you could try "-j accept"  though that may not pass it up to layer 3 filtering.

What are you trying to achieve by maintaining layer2 information?